# Vote has no confirmation/undo

Tags: support, voting

If somebody clicks on up-vote or down-vote accidentaly, what is the way to undo it? or shoudn't it ask for confirmation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                     Click on upvote to give +1
```

[image]

---

```
              Click again on upvote to undo your upvote
```

[image]

---

```
    Click on the number to know how many +1 and -1 is given to this post
```

[image]

---

```
                     Here this post got +124 and -1
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To view vote count you must be a [established-user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: or use a [script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)